# Subarrays divisible by three over a range in a Segment tree

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-tree

I have an array consist of decimal digits. Basically, I have to query that in a given range, how many continuous sub-arrays when considered as a decimal number gets divisible by 3.

I am using the basic fact that number is divisible by 3 if sum of its digits is divisible by 3. So, it felt like a modified form of range over a sum i.e. segment tree problem. I am using bottom-up approach to build the segment tree in which I put a counter of required sub-arrays in each node. But, I am having problems with leading zeros.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Are there update operations on the array? Leading zeros are not allowed in a valid number, right?

Comment: Solved here.
Check this  link.
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/268022/efficient-algorithm-to-count-number-of-substrings-divisible-by-3

Comment: @ILoveCoding yes, there are update operations. Also, leading zeroes are allowed.
eg. Let's say given array is {0,1,2,4,5}. Then, {0,1,2} and {1,2} are considered different.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved in O(N) run-time complexity. I wrote the algorithm in Python, take a look at the code:

```
s = [0, 0, 0]
arr = [0, 3, 0, 3]
count_map = [0]*(len(arr)+1)

for i,n in enumerate(arr):
    r = n % 3
    s = [s[(3 + (j - r))%3] for j in [0, 1, 2]]
    s[r] += (0 if n == 0 else 1)
    count_map[i+1] = count_map[i] + s[0]

print(count_map[len(arr)])
```

Above algorithm prints 4. To get count in range [i, j] (i and j included) do: `count_map[j+1] - count_map[i]`

Here is link for JsFiddle to try it out. http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/179/

### Explanation

For a number to be divisible by 3; sum of all its digits must be divisible by three. Thus we can apply basic modulus maths and map variables to find all the sub-arrays that are divisible by 3. More details:

```
a = [1, 5]
m = [1 % 3, 5 % 3] = [1, 2]
Therefore [1, 5] ie. 15 is divisible as summations of its modulus [1, 2] is divisible by 3
```

Idea is to break summations of numbers into summations of their remainders with 3. The `s` in above algorithm tracks the number of contiguous sub-arrays that yields remainder 0, 1, 2 at current iteration of for-loop.

For example: At i = 3, s[0] is number of contiguous sub-array within range (0, i - 1) such that their remainder with 3 is 0 (basically divisible by 3). Important update step is:

```
s = [s[(3 + (j - r))%3] for j in [0, 1, 2]]
```

Basically, if at current iteration remainder of element is `2` then I can use contiguous sub-arrays with remainder `1` to make sub-arrays with remainder `0` and so on. And if current element is 0 then we can ignore the update of s[0] count or keep the previous count only.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by dynamic programming and ignore numbers with leading zeros as follows. Let A(n,0), A(n,1), A(n,2) be the count of numbers that end at position n, that do not have leading zeros, where A(n,j) counts the number of such numbers that give a remainder of j when divided by 3. It is fairly straightforward to see how to compute the A(n,j) in increasing order according to increasing n, given the values of A(n-1,j), because the remainder of a number when divided by 3 is the same as the remainder of the sum of its digits. Then the sum of all the A(n,0) over all n gives you your answer. Let me know if you'd like more details.